# Grails test-app unit failure

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I'm trying running the grails test-app unit but the following error is showed

```
| Error Fatal error running tests: Error creating bean with name 'br.com.bstes.ProductAgreementController': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productAgreementService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productService': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fiscalClassificationService': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in /home/xman/desenv/xa/xa-one/target/test-reports
```

Grails test unit start the tomcat app too?

I need run this tests similar junit tests in java.

How do this?

Comment: `Use --stacktrace to see the full trace` What's the full stacktrace?

Comment: You can either change the test to integration test or use mocking.

Comment: Hi to solve my problema i use the following plugin  org.gebish:geb-spock:$gebVersion and running with " grails test-app unit:"

Comment: To solve I ran: "grails test-app -unit"